# multiple png images over a single pipe to ffmpeg (no file writes to disk!)

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, png

I have a program that generates a script for `gnuplot`, which in turn generates a lot of png images and send it to `stdout`. I want to pipe these images to ffmpeg *without writing them to the disk*. This is my command line so far:

```
./myprogram | gnuplot | ffmpeg -c:v png -i - -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 24 output.mkv
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be the way, ffmpeg complains "pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input".

Is there a way or am I forced to dump the numbered pngs to disk and then pass ffmpeg something like `-i %10.png`?

Comment: Hm, this is beyond my FFmpeg knowledge, but I'm not too sure this is supposed to work that way – maybe you need a FIFO? See [here](http://www.iabaldwin.com/2011/02/piping-raw-data-info-ffmpeg/).

Comment: @slhck well, that pages shows how to create a pipe in C and stream raw image data. That would be welcome too, if I know a command line program that can do the conversion png->raw image array.

Comment: try to use `-f image2pipe`

Comment: @leepfrog with some fiddling, it works! feel free to post the answer. Anyway, there are some quirks, it does not seem to work with piped png images. The program that generates the image is gnuplot, and I had to switch its output to pbm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `-f image2pipe`, it is not documented on the official documentation but worked for my for a similar issue

Comment: jpeg works, png support has been added 9/5/2012, pbm is broken (https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1321), gif is broken.